# How to read properly from a file

Tags: c

Hello! I'm trying to solve the Longest Common Subsequence problem and i'm crashing on a problem that has nothing to do with the problem itself.
I dont think my program isnt showing the right final result because its not reading properly both sequences

The code of the main function where I read the the sequences from one single file(first line is the first sequence, second line is the second sequence) and is here where I believe the error is.

```
int main(){
    FILE *file;
    char c;
    int m=0, n=0, flag=0;
    file=fopen("test.txt","r");
    if(file==NULL){
        printf("Error opening file.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    if(file){
        while((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF){
            if(c!=' ' && c!='\n' && flag==0)
                m++;
            if(c=='\n')
                flag=1;
            if(c!=' ' && c!='\n' && flag==1)
                n++;
        }
    }

    char X[m], Y[n];
    int i=0;

    if(file){
        while((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF){
            if(c!=' ' && c!='\n' && flag==0){
                i++;
                X[i]=c;
            }
            if(c=='\n'){
                flag=1;
                i=0;
            }               
            if(c!=' ' && c!='\n' && flag==1)
                i++;
                Y[i]=c;
        }
    }
    int j;
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
            printf("%c | %c",X[i],Y[i]);

    }



    printf("Length of LCS is %d .\n", lcs( X, Y, m, n ) );

    return 0;
}
```

this is what it returns when im printing the first sequence.
7 | É  | Û  | ©  | È  | ³  |   |    |

Sorry for the long post.
Thank you in advance for anyone willing to help

Comment: Note: With `char c; ... while((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF){`, best to use `int c;`.

Answer (score 2):

The first `while` loop consumes all the contents of the file, because it runs until `fgetc()` returns `EOF`. The second `while` loop does not run at all, because the file has been exhausted. The arrays `X[]` and `Y[]` remain uninitialised.

Not to mention that once you have handled the case `file == NULL` there is no need to check whether it has magically become `NULL` -- the `if (file)` statements are useless.